# Lombok prefix configurations in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations, android-studio, lombok

I'm using Lombok to generate accessor methods. I have my `lombok.config` file in `module/src/main/java` directory. The config file looks like this.

```
lombok.accessors.prefix += m
config.stopBubbling = true
```

I have the following in my code.

`@Setter String mRoute;`

This seems to generate the function `getMRoute()` instead of `getRoute()`.

I've tried changing the location of the `lombok.config` file, and even installed the Lombok Plugin for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `@Accessors(prefix = "m")` before the class declaration fixes the issue.

```
@Accessors(prefix = "m")
public class MyClass {
    @Getter private int mNum;
}
```

will generate `getNum()` instead of `getMNum()`

Comment: this is nice. However I still have to do it for every class, isn´t there a more "global" solution?

Comment: @dan `lombok.accessors.prefix += m` in lombok.config works fine

Answer (score -1):

I think Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, and does not yet support lombok.config files.

Comment: It does as of May 2017.